# How to split existing collection in Camel

Tags: apache-camel

I have a producer which sends a `Set<Status>`. I want to split the `Set` so downstream components have to process single `Status` objects. My route looks like this:

```
public Set<Status> loadStatus() { ... }

from("direct:start").
    split().
    to("mock:end");

ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBody("direct:start", loadStatuses());
```

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the [Camel Splitter](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) documentation describes how a Collection, Iterator or Array can be used...

> A common use case is to split a Collection, Iterator or Array from the
>   message. In the sample below we simply use an Expression to identify
>   the value to split.

```
from("direct:splitUsingBody").split(body()).to("mock:result");

from("direct:splitUsingHeader").split(header("foo")).to("mock:result");
```

> In Spring XML you can use the Simple language to identify the value to
>   split.

```
<split>
   <simple>${body}</simple>
   <to uri="mock:result"/>
</split>

<split>
   <simple>${header.foo}</simple>
   <to uri="mock:result"/>
</split>
```

Comment: I never noticed that section. Thanks for your time.

Comment: yep, I updated our documentation just yesterday to clarify this area...it was spread out a bit before

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the docs are a bit unclear: none of the examples explicitly mention having a body that's a Java collection. The solution is to split the body without any expression. In that case, Camel will use it's internal conversion engine to return an `Iterator` from a `Set`. The final route is:

```
from("direct:start").
   split(body()).
   to("mock:end");
```

Found a reference in the [Camel JDBC samples](https://camel.apache.org/jdbc.html#JDBC-Samples) documentation:

```
from("direct:hello")
    // here we split the data from the testdb into new messages one by one
    // so the mock endpoint will receive a message per row in the table
    .to("jdbc:testdb").split(body()).to("mock:result");
```